# Where to buy metro bus tickets near Frihamnen Cruise Terminal, Stockholm Sweden

Tags: trains, tickets, buses, cruising

In Sept. 2022 we are arriving at Frihamnen Cruise Terminal (Frihamnsgatan, 115 41), Stockholm Sweden. We must purchase metro bus tickets before getting on the bus. There is an ICA Kvantum Grocery Store at Malmvägen 13 115 41, a short walk. Does that chain sell single-use or even better, 24-hour tickets?

I looked at many options with no answers. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: "We must purchase metro bus tickets before getting on the bus". Not really true, you can tap a contactless card to purchase a single ticket on the bus, or are you finding a way to pay by cash?

Comment: "I looked at many options with no answers". What options has you discarded? Is the app an alternative for you?

Comment: I would prefer to get a 24-hour Senior ticket because of the flexibility and simplicity. We will be in stockholm for 2 days only. I am afraid that our contactless US based credit cards may not work on the bus reader or in the phone app.

Comment: I have communicated with the SL Stockholm transit people. They tell me the one remaining ticket machine near the cruise terminal, at the Frihamnen southbound Bus Stop will no longer be there when we visit Stockholm, in Sept. 2022. Also, the nearby ICA Kvantum grocery stopped selling paper tickets during the last ticket up grade. The closest place to buy paper tickets to the cruise terminal is the Gardet Metro station approx. half hour walk. They also stressed that you can easily buy a one way ticked on board the bus with the phone APP or debit card.

Comment: I also expected Gärdet metro stop to be the closest place to buy tickets, but now we know. You can add that as an answer. If you're lucky there might be some arrival service for cruise passengers that sells tickets, for example there is a shed by the bus stop, so keep your eyes open when you arrive. If you want to try the contactless for a single ticket you can register for discounted fare here, partly in Swedish with some instructions in English: https://sl.se/en/in-english/fares--tickets/contactless-pay-as-you-go/your-journeys-with-contactless-pay-as-you-go/

Comment: Thank you Anders! Your idea about impromtu tickets sellers is a good one. My backup plan will be buying the senior 24 hour ticket at the Gardet Metro Station, then take the subway to Gamla Stan.